# how to improve performance of multi activity app?

Tags: java, android

I am making an app, it has more than 10 activities.
when the app is running and after openning nearly 5 activities it crashes as out of memory error, i want to avoid that error

I use this code to navigate betwwen activities

```
Intent intent = new Intent ( thisactivity.this, destination.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Information is very insufficient. Please share information and learn for how to Ask question in SO.

Comment: you should use launch modes in android by adding flags whether you want to have other activity in stack or not based on your requirements

Comment: how to make this ?

Comment: Add code for both activities, i.e source activity and destination activity and also logcat error log.

Comment: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Comment: @AlphaNet you should read how android launchmode works before jumping in. here this can help you https://blog.mindorks.com/android-task-and-back-stack-review-5017f2c18196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I don't think the cause is your activity. Simply call `finish()` when exiting any activity just to be safe. In your drawable folder, ensure that you are using images of less than 70kb in size since this is the most common mistake people do when they run out of memory